# microsite styling with sass

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-5

Using foundation 5 and Sass Im building a website with four components or 'microsites' whose content is markedly different. Additionally, the styling will be also be entirely different. From typefaces and images and specifically color, all four components with have completely different aesthetics.

The layout and structure of all four components or 'microsites' however, will be almost identical.

**My question is:**
Can sass be setup or configured for handling all the necessary styling in terms of layout in a single interation and then have color definitions, typefaces and other styling elements passed through to all of it's sibling styles as variables of some sort?

**I have considered:**
    - Creating four separate partial scss files with the appropriate differences and importing them based on the active 'microsite.'
    *I would prefer a more elegant solution if possible*
    - A javascript solution to detect and apply the necessary changes

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely possible with SASS and would actually be relatively easy.  SASS has the concept of variables and by using partial files you could have all your colors, fonts, typography, etc contained within their own files so they would easy to swap out based on each microsite.